# How can I send Json Data from python to javascipt

Tags: javascript, python, django, fetch

i have this segment of code in a django view (views.py) that returns me a json document, I would like this json document to be sent to a javascript file using fetch. Hope you can help me

```
def get_all_monitors_with_last_data(request):
    token_type = "Bearer"
    user = request.user
    company_user = CompanyUser.objects.get(user=user)
    company = Company.objects.get(id=company_user.company_id)
    refresh_time = 60*60*3
    now = int(time.time())
    get_last_datetime_data = company.last_date_token
    u_get_last_datetime_data = int(get_last_datetime_data.timestamp()) + refresh_time
    if(company.token == None or u_get_last_datetime_data < now):
        token = get_token(company.username, company.password, company.config_grant, company.client_id, company.client_secret)
        if(token != {}):
            company.last_date_token = datetime.now()
            company.token = token["access_token"]
            company.save()
    token_access = company.token
    BASE_API = "http://url";
    req = {}
    params = {}
    try:
        req = requests.get(BASE_API+"/urlcomplements/",
            params = {},
            headers = {
                'Content-Type': "json",
                'Authorization': token_type + " " + token_access
            }).json();
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        req = {}
    return JsonResponse(req, safe=False)
```

Comment: What have you tried yet? Can you show your JavaScript code as well as the urls.py that sets up this view?

Answer (score 0):

You can always return a http response on Django. on your view.py take a look at this sample code.

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse


payload = {"status": False,
               "description": "this is a JSON Response"
          }

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(payload, indent=2),
                        content_type='application/json',
                        status=200)
```

Comment: The OP is already returning a JsonResponse from their code which is a slightly nicer solution compared to your's. And they are probably asking about the receiving end.

Comment: exactly friend, I need to receive that json in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can just use JsonResponse() that is provided by django.

You can refer to this - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#id4